# How to evaluate from the number of solutions for $\sin 2x +\cos 3x - \sin 4x = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem is as follows:

> First find the number of solutions for the equation from below:
>
> Assume $x \in [0,2\pi]$
>
> $\sin 2x +\cos 3x - \sin 4x = 0$
>
> Let $n$ be the number of solutions. Using this $n$ find the sum for:
>
> $5\tan^2\left(\frac{n\pi}{18}\right)+1.5n^2$

I'm not sure how to solve this, what it came to my mind was this:

$\sin 2x +\cos 3x - \sin 4x = 0$

$\sin 4x - \sin 2x - \cos 3x = 0$

Using Prosthaphaeresis formulas then I'm getting to:

$\cos 3x \cdot (2\sin x - 1)=0$

From this it can be inferred that there will be six solutions for

$\cos 3x=0$

In the interval mentioned. Or at least I think so,

these will be:

$\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\frac{3\pi}{6}$, $\frac{5\pi}{6}$, $\frac{7\pi}{6}$, $\frac{9\pi}{6}$, $\frac{11\pi}{6}$.

While for the other guy it will be this:

$\sin x = \frac{1}{2}$

There will be two solutions in that interval, namely:

$\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\frac{5\pi}{6}$

Thus the number of solutions between the two would be eight. But when replacing **in what it is being asked** it doesn't seem to yield something reasonable.

Therefore can someone help me here?. Which part went wrong?.

Comment: Graph out your function, there are $4$ solutions in the domain

Comment: Weird, all of your solutions are right, but it's only showing $4$

Answer (score 3):

The solutions you got for $\sin x =\frac 1 2$ are already included in the other six solutions you got. So $n=6$ and the answer is $5\tan^{2}(\frac {\pi} 3)+(1.5)(36)=69$.

Comment: Nice ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

I Think $n=6$.

Algebraically:

$$\sin 2x +\cos 3x -\sin 4x = \\ 2\sin x \cos x +\cos 2x \cos x-2\sin x \cos x \sin x -4 \sin x 
 \cos x \cos 2x= \\ 2 \sin x \cos x +(1-2 \sin^2 x)\cos x - 2 \sin^2 x \cos x -2 \sin x \cos x(2-4 \sin^2 x) = \\ 2 \sin x \cos x (1-2+4 \sin^2 x) + \cos x (1- 2 \sin^2 x - 2 \sin^2 x)= \\ 2\sin x \cos x(-1+4\sin^2 x) + \cos x (1-4 \sin^2 x)=  \\ 2\sin x \cos x(4\sin^2 x -1) - \cos x (4 \sin^2 x -1)= \\ (4 \sin^2 x -1)(\cos x)(2\sin x -1)=0 $$

so we have as solutions: $\frac{7\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6},\frac{11\pi}{6}$ for the first term, $\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}$ for the second, and $\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6}$ for the third. Six solutions in total.